# .NET core controller not receiving correct input from query string

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular-httpclient

I have an Angular client making requests to a .NET core API. There are two functions that are nearly identical, one works, and the other does not. I can not figure out what the difference is.

Here are the two functions on the client side using the angular/common/httpclient:

```js
getInstitutionSettings(institutionId: string): Promise<any | undefined> {
    return this.http
            .get<InstitutionSettingsModel>('https://localhost:7205/api/v1/Settings/get', {
                params: {
                    id: institutionId,
                },
            })
            .toPromise();
}

getAllInstitutionSettings(): Promise<any | undefined> {
    return this.http
            .get<InstitutionSettingsModel[]>('https://localhost:7205/api/v1/Settings/getAll', {
                params: {
                    id: this.tempTestOrgId,
                },
            })
            .toPromise();
}
```

Here are the C# controller methods that receive the requests:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("get")]
    [EnableCors]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] Guid instId)
    {
        SettingsReadRequestModel req = new SettingsReadRequestModel()
        {
            Id = instId,
            JsonWebToken = this.TestJwt,
            CancellationToken = CancellationToken.None
        };

        if (instId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            SettingsGetResponseModel res = await this.Service.GetSettingsAsync(req);
            return this.Ok(res.Institution);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.BadRequest();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getall")]
    [EnableCors]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll([FromQuery] Guid id)
    {
        SettingsReadRequestModel req = new SettingsReadRequestModel()
        {
            Id = id,
            JsonWebToken = this.TestJwt,
            CancellationToken = CancellationToken.None
        };

        SettingsGetAllResponseModel res = await this.Service.GetAllSettingsAsync(req);

        if (id != Guid.Empty)
        {
            return this.Ok(res.Institutions);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

The differences in the functions are a matter of what scope the input GUID is.  `GetAll()` accepts a parent identifier that returns a list and this is the function that works as expected

`Get()` accepts an identifier for a specific entity and returns only one entity. This method never receives the correct input.

In both cases the two functions in the client send a valid GUID in string format in the query string. I have verified this in the debugger. And in both controller methods, the arguments have the `[FromQuery]` attribute and are expecting a GUID.

EDIT: I think it might be worth noting that in the client, the class variable `this.tempTestOrgId` is hard coded and is implicitly typed. It has no type identifier

`private tempTestOrgId = 'e41093cb-1f42-4f70-802b-64503e24a2b6';`

In `GetAll()` the function receives the correct GUID from the client
In `Get()` the function always receives an Empty GUID (all 0's) even though the client passes in a correctly formatted GUID as a string.

What am I missing? Why does one function work as expected and the other does not?

Comment: It would have been extremely helpful if you could show examples of "good" and "bad" HTTP response payloads (e.g. from Postman).  Nevertheless - please look at Valuator's response below.  Please "upvote" and/or "accept" if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Get` endpoint expects a parameter named `instId`, not `id`. Change your calling function to:

```
getInstitutionSettings(institutionId: string): Promise<any | undefined> {
    return this.http
            .get<InstitutionSettingsModel>('https://localhost:7205/api/v1/Settings/get', {
                params: {
                    instId: institutionId,
                },
            })
            .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Wow I guess I never noticed that the name of the input parameter in the controller mattered. Thank you